# Как менять текст, если изменился ввод?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил свой текст, а программа подсчитывала сколько у него символов, но у меня, если повторно нажать на принять, печатается текст внизу, а мне надо, чтобы сам текст изменялся и не печатался повторно

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("490x205")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title("Длина текста")

def textlen():
    def showtextlen(event=None):
        win.geometry("490x250")
        res = len(Input1.get()) - Input1.get().count(' ')
        myLabel1 = Label(win, text=f"Длина: {len(Input1.get())} символов.\nБез пробелов - {len(Input1.get())} - {Input1.get().count(' ')} = {res} символов", font=("Montserrat", 15))
        myLabel1.pack()
        
    Input1 = StringVar()

    myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Длина текста", font=("Montserrat", 20), highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
    myLabel2.pack()
    myLabel3 = Label(win, text="Введите ваш текст", font=("Montserrat", 18))
    myLabel3.pack()
    myInput1 = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 15), textvariable=Input1)
    myInput1.pack()
    myInput1.bind('<Return>', showtextlen)
    myButton1 = Button(win, text="Принять", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=showtextlen)
    myButton1.pack(ipady=2, pady=12)

textlen()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метку для вывода текста создать заранее и один раз. Ей указать из какой переменной брать текст. Когда надо обновить содержимое которое отображается в метке - просто поменять текст в этой переменной.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("490x205")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title("Длина текста")

def textlen():
    def showtextlen(event=None):
        win.geometry("490x250")
        res = len(Input1.get()) - Input1.get().count(' ')
        Output1.set(f"Длина: {len(Input1.get())} символов.\nБез пробелов: {len(Input1.get())} - {Input1.get().count(' ')} = {res} символов")
        
    Input1 = StringVar()
    Output1 = StringVar()

    myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Длина текста", font=("Montserrat", 20), highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
    myLabel2.pack()
    myLabel3 = Label(win, text="Введите ваш текст", font=("Montserrat", 18))
    myLabel3.pack()
    myInput1 = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 15), textvariable=Input1)
    myInput1.pack()
    myInput1.bind('<Return>', showtextlen)
    myButton1 = Button(win, text="Принять", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=showtextlen)
    myButton1.pack(ipady=2, pady=12)
    myLabel1 = Label(win, textvariable=Output1, font=("Montserrat", 15))
    myLabel1.pack()

textlen()

win.mainloop()
```